# Add a video file instead of recording it

Tags: html, angular, user-experience

In my angular 16.2 app I ask for a video file:

```
<input #file type="file" accept="video/*" ...
```

In mobile devices, android and ios ask if the user wants to select a file or recording it.
Is there any way to avoid this? I just need the file.

The problem is that I have a limited space for upload the video, so with the file I can tell user the file is too big.
If the user record it I can tell the same but after the minutes of the recording and with the user's disappoint (bad UX).

Thanks.